# 3 spans to a row, each in line buy with different widths

Tags: css, css-float, html

I'm trying to have 3 spans in a single row.
The left span is to be a fixed width.
The right span is to float to the right, also a fixed width.
The middle span is to consume the space in between both spans.
These 3 spans are pulled from a database, so there will be multiple rows of differing values in each field except the third span, which will server as a delete button.
I've tried everything to get them to line up and have been successful so far by making the left display: inline-block and float:left, the right: float:right display:inline-block, but the middle just doesn't want to expand to fill the intervening space between the two spans, even after changing it to display:block.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```
/*Left Span*/
.word_native{
float: left;
clear: left;
margin-top: 7px;
height:22px;
line-height:22px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

/*Middle Span*/
.word_foreign{
margin-top: 6px;
height:22px;
height:22px;
line-height:22px;
line-height:22px;
display:inline-block;
}
*/

/*Right Span*/

float: right;
clear: right;
margin-top: 6px;
```

Comment: Do you have some code? It's hard to answer a coding problem without any code.

Comment: Please send code on http://jsfiddle.net so that we can easily debug it

Comment: Put your span rows inside a container div and set a width for that container. It should work then
example - http://jsfiddle.net/kKbxr/

Comment: @GabrielDavisJones: t_virus just gave you a perfect example of how to use jsfiddle.net. Please do that next time.

Comment: Seems like you are using jsfiddle first time. you need to give HTML as well as CSS code and need to place them in proper frames.

Comment: @t_viru I guess your code is broken --http://jsfiddle.net/kKbxr/1/

Comment: @RajivPingale yeah, longer content breaks the layout. I posted a jQuery solution that should work regardless of content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, guys! There's one small problem, though. Whenever I go to style one of the spans, e.g. add a border, the spans in the rows below start to look completely staggered, not maintaining their horizontal positions...

Comment: I've used jfiddle to show you what happens: http://jsfiddle.net/kKbxr/5/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you are doing would be perfect for a table, so why not use an html table?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="word_native">native</td>
        <td class="word_foreign">foreign</td>
        <td class="del">del btn</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="word_native">native</td>
        <td class="word_foreign">foreign</td>
        <td class="del">del btn</td>
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

Then you can set the third column to a fixed width through CSS.